# Stored procedure output in select statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying desperately to call an oracle stored procedure and have the output come out looking like they came from a select statement.

The goal is to embed the sql in other software that can execute sql queries.

Here's a sample of the kind of thing I'd like to be able to do.

```
/* P_DELETE_THIS_TEST IS A STORED PROCEDURE WITH 4 VARCHAR2 PARAMETERS DEFINED AS IN OUT VARIABLES */

DECLARE
   char_1       VARCHAR2(255) := 'TEST';
   char_2       VARCHAR2(255) := '';
   char_3       VARCHAR2(255) := '';
   char_4       VARCHAR2(255) := '';

BEGIN
   P_DELETE_THIS_TEST(char_1, char_2, char_3, char_4);
   SELECT char_1, char_2, char_3, char_4 FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not following the "The goal is to embed the sql in other software that can execute sql queries."  Why can't the other software call your `P_DELETE_THIS_TEST()` procedure and just get the values? What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: The other software can't get outbound values from a stored procedure.
It can either:
A. fire-and-forget a SQL statement without recognizing any output
 or
B. get columns back from a SQL query.

I want to execute a procedure, but have the output comeback as if from a select statement.
If I can't pull that off, I suppose I can pass in a GUID and have the proc insert into a dummy table when it's done. Then I can just query the dummy table after executing the stored proc. That's like plan C or plan D...

Comment: Hi @P.B. Check table functions in oracle i think that will solve your problem

Comment: Your plan C/D sounds like it wants a global temporary table; being session-specific would remove the GUID (if I understand you). A pipelined function might work if you can create types. But how does the application execute and receive results; could it handle a ref cursor result form a function call as part of a query, say?

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole Inserting into a Global Temp table and then just open a cursor selecting from the temp table. Once the session is dropped by the client the data in the temp table will disappear. I think that would be a very reasonable way to handle this.

Comment: It has to be a stored proc and not a function as part of what it's doing is inserting records in another table. I'll just make a temporary table. I was hoping I didn't have to.  Thanks for the input everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dynamic sql.
The following PL/SQL block contains several examples of dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
   plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);
   emp_id      NUMBER(4) := 7566;
   salary      NUMBER(7,2);
   dept_id     NUMBER(2) := 50;
   dept_name   VARCHAR2(14) := 'PERSONNEL';
   location    VARCHAR2(13) := 'DALLAS';
   emp_rec     emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE bonus (id NUMBER, amt NUMBER)';
   sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO dept VALUES (:1, :2, :3)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING dept_id, dept_name, location;
   sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = :id';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO emp_rec USING emp_id;
   plsql_block := 'BEGIN emp_pkg.raise_salary(:id, :amt); END;';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING 7788, 500;
   sql_stmt := 'UPDATE emp SET sal = 2000 WHERE empno = :1
      RETURNING sal INTO :2';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING emp_id RETURNING INTO salary;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM dept WHERE deptno = :num'
      USING dept_id;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE TRUE';
END;
```